# Why doesn't forEach() print anything when iterating over this array of length 10?

Tags: javascript

> Why doesn't forEach() print anything when iterating over this array of length 10?

I don't understand why `forEach()` doesn't print anything when looping over the elements in `dist`?

I see that `console.log(dist.length)` is `10`, still nothing happens.

```
  var dist = new Array(10);

  for (var i = 0; i < dist.lengh; ++i) {
    dist[i] = new Array(n);
    dist[i].fill(Infinity);
  }

  dist.forEach(n => console.log('xXx'));
```

Comment: did you debug your code?!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo there, its `length`, not `lengh`:

```js
var dist = new Array(10);
var n = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < dist.length; ++i) {
  dist[i] = new Array(n);
  dist[i].fill(Infinity);
}

dist.forEach(n => console.log('xXx'));
```

As to your second question:

`new Array(10)` creates empty array of size 10 (with 10 empty slots). You need to initialize the values first to be able to iterate the array. When you create array like this, it will not have 10 times `undefined` value, there is no value at all. Try to use `console.log(new Array(10))`, you will see something like `10 x empty`.

Comment: Why doesn't it work anyway? In case of this type, the array still has an initial size of 10?

Comment: Not it is not. new Array(10) creates empty array of size 10 (with 10 empty slots). You need to initialize the values first to be able to iterate the array.

Comment: When you create array like this, it will not have 10 times `undefined` value, there is no value at all. Try to use `console.log(new Array(10))`, you will see something like `10 x empty`.